# Wine Steam not working (Ubuntu 17.04)

Tags: wine, steam

I recently used wine to install steam on my 17.04 system... but after installation, it does not connect to the internet, hence nothing is loading. However, it does print this error

```
[0623/151506:ERROR:child_process_launcher.cc(443)] Failed to launch child process
```

Comment: @DavidFoerster Maybe I'm missing something but I don't see the referenced error message in the duplicate candidate, so I can't CV :(.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: The point of my duplicate link is to show OP how to install Steam in Wine *correctly*. If the issue persists, we can still work on that, but now we can be reasonably sure that the installation procedure was somewhat sane.

Comment: @DavidFoerster hopefully reinstallation the *sane* way solves the error message. In the meantime I've burned up my 20 CV's for the day and can no longer dup it. Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

I run my Windows version of Steam under wine with the following script

```
cd /home/[your-user-name]/.wine/drive_c/"Program Files (x86)"/Steam
export WINEPREFIX=$HOME/.steam
export WINEDEBUG=-all
nice -n 19 wine Steam.exe
```

Perhaps it will work for you as well.